# GWT plugin for Eclipse not shown , mac os x 10.10.1

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, osx-yosemite, google-plugin-eclipse

trying learn GWT framework. 
have installed Eclipse Luna and GWT Plugin for Eclipse. 
when i open new project in IDE there is no any Google options, although software are installed ( see picture bellow)

what can it be ?

[image: installed plugins]
[image: no google folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, 
it was required Oracle Java 1.7 and and specify the JVM updating/adding parameter -vm in eclipse.ini file